# Passing arguments to PostgreSQL plpgsql

Tags: postgis, plpgsql

I have a PostGIS query which works fine on its own:

```
select distinct
    gis.filelinks_qtrqtrs_view.entity,
    gis.filelinks_qtrqtrs_view.type,
    gis.filelinks_qtrqtrs_view.url
from
    public.intersection_layer as f,
    gis.filelinks_qtrqtrs_view
where
    st_intersects(f.geom,gis.filelinks_qtrqtrs_view.geom) = true;
```

I want to create a plpgsql function which will perform this query with the table 'public.intersection_layer' passed to it. The template that I have created:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gis.get_poly_fence(table_name text)
  RETURNS TABLE (entity text,type text,url text)
AS $$
BEGIN
    return query select distinct
        gis.filelinks_qtrqtrs_view.entity,
        gis.filelinks_qtrqtrs_view.type,
        gis.filelinks_qtrqtrs_view.url
    from
        table_name as f,
        gis.filelinks_qtrqtrs_view
    where
        st_intersects(f.geom,gis.filelinks_qtrqtrs_view.geom) = true;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I pass a query:

```
select * from gis.get_poly_fence('public.intersection_layer');
```

I get an error of "relation "table_name" does not exist. I can't find any way of delimiting the tablename 'public.intersection_layer' argument that works to pass to the 'gis.get_poly_fence' function. I've used functions before (obviously not too many)-- what is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify table names dynamically in a function you need to construct dynamic SQL and use the PL/pgSQL `EXECUTE` statement.  The Postgres [manual section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) on this has an example.

Comment: It is also good idea to pass tables as regclass type, which force user to pass only existing postgres relations. Then, you can cast it back to text to retrieve relation names.

Comment: I suggest to use `FORMAT()` with the `%I` specifier, rather than requesting a `REGCLASS` input; this allows for better error handling, i.e. you can always check if the given `TEXT` parameter is a valid relation identifier by casting to `REGCLASS`, but you should use `TO_REGCLASS` to be able to handle `NULL` cases: `IF TO_REGCLASS($1) THEN <query> ELSE RAISE EXCEPTION 'Know your tables, stupid!' END IF;`

Comment: @ThingumaBob it looks pretty much equal to me in case you want force user to provide existing relations or raise an exception. When typed parameter is used, it fails even befor it enters the function body... Maybe when I want to log something or so...

Comment: @DavidP your function, your error handling

Comment: I accepted the answer given by @dr_jts, but I'm still flummoxed by the fact that you can't easily pass a static tablename in a function. I decided to hardcode the tablename in the function body. Thanks for the other comments as well.